# How to make paths clickable in Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, clickable

I have VSCode vs. 1.3. and I would like to be able to click in any valid path showed inside the integrated Terminal and get the file opened.

Do you know how can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you have full paths it works, but not for relative paths. would love to have a workspace setting for it, it should only be to apply the `pwd`(bash) and `(pwd).Path`(powershell) in front of it.

No link for relative links:

```
File ".\unity_events.py", line 100, in get_latest_event
```

If full path is applied it is fine (ctrl+click):

```
File "d:\sensio-data\sensiotools\sensiotools\mssql.py", line 410, in psql
```

Comment: Have just implemented this in a command line utility and I can confirm that relative paths are now working (v1.74) but can't say when the change might have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.65 (Feb. 2022) will introduce a new `Terminal: Open` command which provides an alternative to Ctrl+click, and works for opening files.

See [issue 140923](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140923) and [issue 141342](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141342)

> Prior to this work, a mouse click was required to activate terminal links.
>
> We now provide 3 commands in order to make them actionable via the keyboard:
> [image: Screen Shot 2022-01-24 at 6 05 20 PM]
>
> Most Recent refers to the link closest to the cursor position.